# In the figure calculate x as a function of theta

Tags: geometry

I tried to find some relationships but I can't finish

$\triangle ABC: \theta +180-2\beta-180-2\alpha = 180\\\boxed{2(\beta+\alpha)-\theta = 180}(I)\\\boxed{\alpha+\beta + 2(ϕ+ω) = 360}(II)\\(I)em(II): 90+\frac{\theta}{2}+2(ϕ+ω) =360 \rightarrow \boxed{\theta + 4(ϕ+ω) = 540(III)}...???\\
Answer: 60^o - \theta$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at $\triangle PMN$ I would have thought you may have $$x+\phi+\omega=180^\circ$$

which with your (I) and (II) I think leads to $$x=45^\circ +\frac\theta 4$$

This is more plausible than  $x=60^\circ - \theta$ since there is clearly the possibility of having every labelled angle, including $x$ and $\theta$, equal to $60^\circ$

Comment: Perfect, the answer is wrong. Your reasoning is correct. Thank you very much